# How to get access token using refresh token AzureAD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I want to get access token with the help of refresh token that I got previously.

I got tokens using scope: `user.read offline_access openid` in oauth2 endpoint:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant.com/v2.0/token

After a couple of hours, access token expired. Now I am trying to get this using refresh token.

But I'm unsuccessful in it, any help is much needed.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created one Azure AD application and added **`API permissions`** as below:

[image]

With below **parameters**, I got the **`tokens`** via Postman:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:appID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
client_secret:client_secret
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**
[image]

In order to get access token using above refresh token, change **grant type** to **`refresh_token`**.

I got the **access token** successfully using refresh token with parameters like below:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:appID
grant_type:refresh_token
refresh_token: 0.AVYA_in0zaI3eUqOQHrbrD-FUv //paste the refresh token that you got above
client_secret:client_secret //Mandatory if client is web app
```

**Response:**
[image]

Comment: Perfect! got it

Comment: How do you do it without a client secret?

Comment: @Sridevi When I used the above access token API with tenant id, it results as "The passed grant is from a personal Microsoft account and is required to be sent to the /consumers or /common endpoint". When trying to use access token API as https://login.microsoftonline.com/common.oauth2/v2.0/token, it results in returning only access token. Please suggest on this. I have given all the permission as you did in screenshot.

Comment: But I have multitenant, supported type

Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)

Comment: https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token is for single tenant applications. For multi-tenant, you need to use https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token for generating token. If you are still facing issue, kindly post new question with more details on what you are doing

Comment: @Sridevi Please find the below URL, as new question is added. Suggestion on the same.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77445364/how-to-get-access-token-from-refresh-token-without-using-tenant-id

Comment: @Sridevi I am trying to obtain access and refresh tokens using an authorization code in common endpoint URL(Multi-tenant). The process is unsuccessful for the email associated with the Azure AD where the application is registered. However, it works for other personal account emails(tested), providing the refresh token. I have the necessary permissions for Delegated - Offline access, openid, User.Read.
Error: AADSTS70000: The request was denied because one or more scopes.
URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
Scope:'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access'

Comment: Please provide Suggestion on above scenario