# How to get access token from refresh token without using tenant id?

Tags: laravel, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Using below URL, I get the code.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=appId
&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/auth/microsoft/callback
&response_type=code  
&response_mode=query  
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

Now, I generated access token and refresh token via Postman with below parameters including code value:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id=appId
grant_type=authorization_code
scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access
client_secret=client_secret
code=M.C105_BAY.2.1d853a8b-20f2-xxxx-xxxx-d37779217xxx
redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/auth/microsoft/callback
```

I have successfully got the access token and refresh token.

Now, I am trying to get access token using refresh token in below API,

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:refresh_token
redirect_uri:http://localhost:8000/microsoft/sso/callback
client_id=appId
client_secret=client_secret
refresh_token:M.C105_BAY.-CcIfFlVtnsRVHLnEtb0PnIZAvXWez8thRn8rQ91qZ86nMpDUw9Wt08ezOOlzR!mlDDs*ijok5X3y1YHZ*hTSpG!jgwQdXI8atQRVGWXkV8LzJFlUXvdZnxB3PZRmFZGm!eTg5Y0TPiyXOQzWEDHkkVVOzOb91KRQ!0qCW5ayM226JMju*thcINXIZbq6aoCRo!XqUGYusb90oSGqSZrfH48mBQXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXSr0ga1X42RDpU6jRQmx6cYKFvC56D*XrfkFjwJN!y9fk0fm9Vt1xnmlignR!PfZujKQtXXXXXO35FNc$
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

I get the below error,
[image]

Please suggest on this to get the access token.

Comment: I ran the same and able to get access token using refresh token. Check [this](https://i.imgur.com/oUsDdqw.png). Could you include `Headers` section of your Postman request?

Comment: The error _AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'_ might occur if you are not passing `Content-Type` header properly with request.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the header in Content-Type as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". After removing, it is fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error *"AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following
> parameter: 'grant_type'"* usually occurs if you are not passing
> `Content-Type` header properly with request.

When I passed request body in **`form-data`** and added **header** as `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, I too got **same error** as below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:refresh_token
client_id=appId
client_secret=client_secret
refresh_token:refresh_token
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To resolve the error, you need to either delete `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`  header that you added manually or pass request body in **x-www-form-urlencoded** form.

In my case, I passed request body in **x-www-form-urlencoded** form without removing `Content-type` header and got access token like below:

```php
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:refresh_token
client_id=appId
client_secret=client_secret
refresh_token:refresh_token
```

**Response:**

[image]

If you prefer passing the request body in **form-data**, make sure to **delete** the  `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`  header that you manually added.

Comment: Okay, sure. It worked